# programmatically switching "triple-monitors"

Tags: c++, windows-7, desktop, multiple-monitors

I have a VR920, and wish my app to automatically switch from dual-monitors desktop to third vga device (VR920) whilst retaining my previous primary monitor, these two then still being extended desktop. On Windows 7.

EnumDisplayDevices()/etc only has access to the two active monitors (and virtuals?), so I cannot locate the VR920 device.

Futhermore, from where can I get/set desktop icons positional info, now no IActiveDesktop exists ?

Thankyee.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but this is the best multimonitor site I know.

http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/

http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/forum/forums.asp